# What is wrong with my recursive generate all permutations algorithm (repeats forever)

Tags: python, recursion, permutation, dynamic-programming

I've written an algorithm to produce all permutations of a list of numbers, and it seems as though I'm almost there. However, once we have recurred down to a single number, it will loop forever. Take a look at my code below:

```
def permute(nums):
    if len(nums) == 0 or len(nums) == 1:
        return [nums]

    perms = []

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        prefix = nums.pop(i)

        for permutation_of_suffix in self.permute(nums):

            print(permutation_of_suffix)

            permutation_of_suffix[:0] = [prefix]

            perms.append(permutation_of_suffix)

        nums.insert(i, prefix)

    return perms
```

As you can see I've added a print statement. If we ran permute([1, 2, 3]) it would simply print

```
[3]
[3]
[3]
```

forever. However, I'm still a novice with recursion and dynamic programming so I can't quite figure out what is going wrong. Obviously, either one of the loops is running forever, or the recursive call is being made infinitely many times.

If anyone could help I'd really appreciate, if you want me to clarify anything don't hesitate to leave a comment and I'll be sure to respond.

Thanks guys,

Comment: What is `self.permute`? And do you have to write it yourself or can you use libraries?

Comment: the same function he create a recursive function just try to remove the self @user7784503

Comment: It's because of the interaction between `return [nums]` and `permutation_of_suffix[:0] = [prefix]`. You're making the `nums` list longer with each iteration, so your function never completes. Use `return [nums.copy()]` instead.

Comment: @user7784503 Hi I need to write it myself, no library usage.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks. Did you have any further recommendations for my style of recursive/dp coding? Sometimes it's hard to remember that python variables are essentially pointers. Cheers.

Comment: pretty sure this isn't dynamic programming, at least not in the way I'd know it used in computer science.  you're just naively using recursion to solve a problem that [doesn't need it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Comment: @SamMason This is dynamic programming, and trying to understand the guts of a famous algorithm isn't naivety.

Comment: @SamMason good DAY sir

Answer (score 0):

you only need to change this line

```
for permutation_of_suffix in permute(nums):
```

to this

```
for permutation_of_suffix in permute(nums.copy()):
```